# Page keeps loading even after I click "Stop" button - Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, website

I randomly notice some pages keep loading even after I click "Stop" button. Loading animation doesn't stop either.

[Here](http://efytimes.com/e1/fullnews.asp?edid=130306) is a page I've noticed this most recently.

This is an issue because I've time based billing on my internet where I live during summer and it is simply not affordable to keep waiting for a page to load entirely (I'm mostly concerned with text only which often loads quickly) and to continue using my entire bandwidth (19KBps so must stop the first one before I can open another).

I have Google Chrome on a Windows Server 2008 box.

**Why is Chrome essentially ignoring "Stop" button?** **And how to Fix?**

Comment: The bigger issue here is limiting the extra stuff Chrome uses bandwidth to load so you can keep your billing low. Solve that and spamming "stop" shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I can stop images, flash content etc. etc. but I want some pages to load fully. Also stop button works fine most of the time as well. Issue arise on the pages which don't stop and I want them to. Why some don't stop? Any idea? Is it something related to page?

Comment: I am interested in this because I use stop often also. From observation stop stops "the rest of the page from loading" it does not stop "processes" therfore if something has begun or a script has started and has timing or events, only stopping the actual process that is now running would help. Depending on the site, hitting stop much faster can help. When all else fails blocking all scripting, or putting the site into a "restricted zone" (no scripts)works.

Answer (score 3):

you can resolve this by installing an addon like [Text Mode](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-mode/adelhekhakakocomdfejiipdnaadiiib) or [Text-Only Mode](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-only-mode/nelklgbagpchkmoipfpcbbjjbdbjhgid?hl=en). I personally prefer Text Mode. These addons block all images, video, flash content. You won't even have to click on stop... Text Mode makes all text grayscale while Text-Only Mode maintains the colors while loading the page. Either work well to ensure you don't consume a lot of bandwidth in loading the page. - Chaitrali